# How to install Mongodb 4 on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mongodb

I am struggling to install Mongodb 4.0 on Ubuntu 15.10 but I am not able to.

I tried Mongodb's official guide too:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

But Mongodb official installation guide has no instructions for Ubuntu 15.10.

When I try to start Mongodb instance I get:

```
Mongodb 4: Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found
```

I also tried to remove Mongodb completely and then fresh install.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Just use Docker!

Comment: Docker? I don't understand. I need to have a Mongo server and its modules  installed on my server. Because i need to mongodump and restore Meteor's database

Comment: With Docker running any software is as easy as running a single Docker run command.

Comment: I have no experience with Docker. I will give it a try, but I don't have much time. I need a quick solution

Comment: Non-LTS Ubuntu releases (like 15.10) only have a 9 month support period, so your O/S reached end of life in July 2016. For the easiest install path I'd suggest upgrading to a newer LTS (Long Term Support) release like Ubuntu 16.04, which is still supported by Canonical and third party vendors like MongoDB. If you need a quick solution you could also try using an online service with a free tier, such as [MongoDB Atlas](http://mongodb.com/atlas). Docker is another option if you want to avoid O/S upgrades or using a hosted service.